# Probability of drawing a cursed coin not from a certain box

Tags: probability, self-study, independence

There are three boxes of gold coins. In the first box, 1 out of 3 coins are cursed, in the second 2 out of 3 are cursed, and in the third 1 out of 4 are cursed. Furthermore, the first box is ornate, and so has 3/5 chance of being picked, while the other two boxes have a 1/5 chance. The experiment consists of selecting a box, and then selecting a coin.

What is the probability that someone drew a cursed coin and did not pick box 1?

My approach:

I recognize that there are non independent events. And to find the probability of not picking box 1 with a cursed coin I need to find the probability of choosing a cursed coin and the other two boxes then add them together.

\begin{align}
P(Curse \cap Box 2) &= P(Box 2)P(Curse | Box 2)\\
&= (1/5)(2/3)\\
&= 2/15
\end{align}

\begin{align}
P(Curse \cap Box 3) &= P(Box 3)P(Curse | Box 3)\\
&= (1/5)(1/4)\\
&= 1/20
\end{align}

\begin{align}
P(Curse \cap Box 2) + P (Curse \cap Box 3) &= 2/15 + 1/20\\
& = 0.1833
\end{align}

Therefore, $P(Curse \cap Not Box 1) = 0.1833$.

I feel like the logic is correct and would like a confirmation.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: I'm informed by the instructor that it is wrong and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Actually I misinterpreted what the instructor said. Thanks for your input.